# Why length max filter dosen't work ? android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a *Button* when this button is pressed the *amount* (amount of my product) will be increased by one .

And also set a *maxlength* for this amount value .

But my code doesn't filter the amount .

this is my adapter :

```
class RecyclerAdapterMain(


    val product: List<Roomtable>,
    val context: Context


) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMain.ViewHolder>() {


    val viewModel: ViewModelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(Application()).create(ViewModelRoom::class.java)

    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemview: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {


        val title: TextView = itemview.product_txt

        val price: TextView = itemview.price_product

        val imageproduct: ImageView = itemview.product_image

        val btn_add_product: Button = itemview.btn_add_product

        var amount_value: TextView = itemview.amount_value

        val button_remove_product: Button = itemview.button_remove_product



    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


        val layoutview =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutview)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = product.size


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val products = product[position]


        holder.title.text = products.title

        holder.price.text = products.price

        Picasso.get().load(products.image).into(holder.imageproduct)

        holder.amount_value.text = products.amount.toString()


        val anim: Animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.anim_for_btn_zoom_out)


        holder.btn_add_product.setOnClickListener {

// this will start an animation on addButton
            it.startAnimation(anim)

            holder.button_remove_product.visibility = View.VISIBLE


            holder.amount_value.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            products.amount++.toString()

            holder.amount_value.text = products.amount.toString()

// this is lengthmax filter but dosen't work

            holder.amount_value.filters = arrayOf(LengthFilter(5))


// this is insert the selected product into roomdatabase

            viewModel.insertItemToCart(
                CartTable(
                    null,
                    products.title,
                    products.price,
                    products.image,
                    products.amount
                )
            )

        }
```

how could filter my amount number correctly ?

what's wrong with my code ?

Thank's in advanced .

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to inform RecyclerView about the change after onClick. You can do it with `notifyDatasetChanged()`. If you are using data class to define 'Product', you can use copy mechanism:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val products = product[position]


        holder.title.text = products.title

        holder.price.text = products.price

        Picasso.get().load(products.image).into(holder.imageproduct)

        holder.amount_value.text = products.amount.toString()


        val anim: Animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.anim_for_btn_zoom_out)


        holder.btn_add_product.setOnClickListener {

// this will start an animation on addButton
            it.startAnimation(anim)

            holder.button_remove_product.visibility = View.VISIBLE


            holder.amount_value.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val changedProducts = products.copy(amount = products.amount++)
            product[holder.adapterPosition] = changedProducts

            holder.amount_value.text = products.amount.toString()

// this is lengthmax filter but dosen't work

            holder.amount_value.filters = arrayOf(LengthFilter(5))


// this is insert the selected product into roomdatabase

            viewModel.insertItemToCart(
                CartTable(
                    null,
                    changedProducts.title,
                    changedProducts.price,
                    changedProducts.image,
                    changedProducts.amount
                )
            )
            notifyDatasetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: But what didn't work and what is not working. Because you're writing about some filter and there is none

Comment: atually when I use notifydatachanged in my code the whole position of my product messed up .  like this, when click on button position 0 the postion 1 is changed . i dont know why .

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me if anyone stuck with this issue  :

```
 val anim: Animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, R.anim.anim_for_btn_zoom_out)

        holder.btn_add_product.setOnClickListener {


            it.startAnimation(anim)
            holder.amount_value.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            products.amount++
            holder.amount_value.text = products.amount.toString()
            if (products.amount == 6) {

              val maxlength = 5
                products.amount = maxlength
                Toast.makeText(context , "limit in order ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
```

I think there is also better ways and this is not good practice but just work now .