# Length filter not work for textview ? - android

Tags: android, kotlin

I also asked the same question in here

[Why length max filter dosen't work ? android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097666/why-length-max-filter-dosent-work-android)

but this is the simple version of that question .

I just want create a simple app .

There is a button And A Textview .

whenever this button is clicked the amount of Text view increased by one .

But I got stuck in the maxlength implementation .

actually , I want this amount goes up just to 5 and no more .

I set filter for the amount but does not work and also the maxlength of xml atrribute is also not work (but I think the maxlength of the xml would be override  ) .

Code :

activity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val number = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.number)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)


        var amount = 1


        button.setOnClickListener {

            amount++

        number.text = amount.toString()

            number.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(5))
            
        }

    }
}
```

xml :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="button" />
```

Thank's for help in advanced .

Comment: `InputFilter.LengthFilter` is used to set maximum length of the text in `TextView`. As I can see you are using it to check if text in `TextView` is greater than 5, it is wrong.

Comment: so waht code shoud i use to set max for my amount ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for the maximum value of the `amount` variable you can use `if` operator:

```
button.setOnClickListener {

    amount++

    if (amount <= 5) {
        number.text = amount.toString()
    }            
}
```